# JS - Setting color of a Object without css with RGB

Tags: javascript, 2d, background-color, rgb, game-development

I Was creating a game using w3spaces(link: https://noobnb.w3spaces.com/.). i have code: and i want to change the color of player (const) with rgb

```
    const createPlayer = (w,h) => {
        const player = document.createElement('div');
        player.style.width = w + 'px';
        player.style.height = h + 'px';
        player.id = "player";
        player.style.down = "150px";
        return player; 
    };
    // const createPlayer creates player
    // part1,2,3 and currentColor is my rgb(from stackoverflow)
    // i want to set my const player background color to currentColor rgb
    // value
```

as comments:
1-const createPlayer creates player
2-part1,2,3 and currentColor is my rgb(from stackoverflow)
3-i want to set my const player background color to currentColor rgb
continue-of-3:4-value

Comment: You've already set the width of `player` with `player.style.width`, for example. Given that knowledge what problem are you having setting the background color?

Comment: Why all the `+1 -0 +0` ???

Comment: Note:  CSS uses `snake-case`, were Javascript uses `camelCase` for style properties.  So you just need to do -> `player.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: @Kokodoko i picked up that code from stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579508/js-setting-color-of-a-object-without-css-with-rgb